# Fail to bypass a spring security check using antMatcher method

Tags: java, security, spring-security, regression, bypass

How should I carefully construct url addresses to bypass forensics in this spring project?

```
public class SpringSecurityConfig
extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Bean
    public HttpFirewall httpFirewall() {
        return new CustomHttpFirewall();
    }

    protected void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
        ((ExpressionUrlAuthorizationConfigurer.AuthorizedUrl)httpSecurity.authorizeRequests().antMatchers(new String[]{"/admin/**"})).authenticated();
    }
}
```

Above is the statement for authentication for this spring project.

And the project have the following statement in the firewall file.

```
public class CustomHttpFirewall
extends DefaultHttpFirewall {
    protected void configure(StrictHttpFirewall firewalledRequest) {
        firewalledRequest.setAllowUrlEncodedSlash(true);
        firewalledRequest.setAllowUrlEncodedDoubleSlash(true);
        firewalledRequest.setAllowUrlEncodedPeriod(true);
    }
}
```

This project doesn't use JWT to authenticate a user.

The version number of spring-security in this project is 5.6.3, while which of springframework is 2.7.0

I've tried multiple ways of double-writing the slash and encoding the url multiple times, but all of them failed.

I wander whether there is even a way to bypass this forensic statement.

Comment: `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` is deprecated

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use **requestMatchers** instead
because isn't **antMatchers** deprecated in the newest **SpringSecurity** version

Comment: Thanks, that's right. But this question is not about development but security. I'm wondering if this outdated approach poses a tangible security risk